# JSP decoded String is not equal to a normal String

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, base64, string-comparison

I'm new to this, so please be patient...
I've found a JSP code snippet that reads out the user data from the header info, and changed it a little bit (made it to a function). The problem is that, the String in return is just nut getting compared well: I did my homework and realized that it must be some kind of char set problem because even the two string lengths don't match, but I can't find the solution. How can I convert any of them to a proper format?

```
<%@ page import="sun.misc.BASE64Encoder" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%!
public String matchuser(String inputUser,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws java.io.IOException
{  

  String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
  String s = "";
  String retval = "kakukk";

  //no auth, request NTLM
  if (auth == null) {
          response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
          response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
          return "no auth";
  }
  //check what client sent
  if (auth.startsWith("NTLM ")) { 
          //System.out.println(auth);  

          byte[] msg = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth.substring(5));
          int off = 0, length, offset;              

          //############################

          if (msg[8] == 1) 
          { 
              off = 18;

              byte z = 0;
              byte[] msg1 =
                  {(byte)'N', (byte)'T', (byte)'L', (byte)'M', (byte)'S',(byte)'S', (byte)'P', 
                  z,(byte)2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z,
                  (byte)40, z, z, z, (byte)1, (byte)130, z, z,
                  z, (byte)2, (byte)2, (byte)2, z, z, z, z, // 
                  z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z};
              // send ntlm type2 msg

              response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
              response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM " 
                 + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1).trim());

                 return "dunno msg[8]";
          } 
          else if (msg[8] == 3) 
          { 
                  off = 30;
                  length = msg[off+17]*256 + msg[off+16];
                  offset = msg[off+19]*256 + msg[off+8];
                  s = new String(msg, offset, length);
                  // print computer name // out.println(s + " ");
          }
          else
          {
            return "done";
          }

          length = msg[off+9]*256 + msg[off+8];
          offset = msg[off+11]*256 + msg[off+10];

          //############################  
          s = new String(msg, offset, length);

          if(s.equals(inputUser))
          {
            return "match";
          }
          else
          {
            return "not match:-" + s + "- input:-" + inputUser+"-";
          }               
  } 
  return "final";        
}         
%>

<%
String fnc = matchuser("u099511",request,response);

out.println(fnc);

%>
```

In the last lines, I call the function with my user (u099511). On the surface the two Strings look the same, but they're not, I can't compare them:

```
not match:-u099511- input:-u099511-
```

What am I missing here?
Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that the returned string was in UTF16LE. Don't ask why, apparently our service management system uses this one...
Anyway, the solution was to declare the result string as utf16le:

```
s = new String(msg, offset, length, "UTF-16LE");
```

If you're such a beginner as I am, you might wanna remember that UTF16 is by default UTF-16BE.